# How to remove element from list and update it?

Tags: c#, list

After removing element in list, I get next problem.

```
ID Name
-------
1 Alexandra
3 David
```

How to update the list to next form?

```
ID Name
-------
1 Alexandra
2 David
```

```
public class LicenseDataGrid { 
    public int Id { get; set; } = 0;
    public string name { get; set; } = string.Empty;
}
```

Comment: I'm not convinced that there's enough detail here to help adequately.  Where does the `ID` come from?  The _index_ of an item in a list is unrelated to any attributes on the object itself.

Comment: _I get next problem_ - what is the problem? Why Id 3 changes into 2, by what logic?

Comment: Is it a list of classes? dictionary? something else? and what is the problem? provide [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: @Guy its list of class `public class LicenseDataGrid
    {
        public int Id { get; set; } = 0;

        public string name{ get; set; } = string.Empty;`

Comment: Is that an Auto-incremented id from a database?

Comment: You would probably have to update all items' ids manually. `LicenseDataGrid` has no concept of a "list".

Comment: An Id is here to identify something, not to provide a line number. An Id should not change.

Comment: Can you provide your code: what is list and how do you delete from it

Comment: "update the list to next form?" what exactly is next form ? what is the logic behind the change in value of Id to 2 ?

Comment: Not sure why you want to change id (it should always stay unique and same), but in this case you need manually change it  (and change ids in whole List too): in foreach loop set up all ids starting from 1

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the comments, in most cases `Id` should not be changed, because it is unique identifying an object. But if you mean *index of an object*, it can be done in the next manner:

```
var list = new List<LicenseDataGrid>
  { 
      new LicenseDataGrid { Id= 1, name = "A"},
      new LicenseDataGrid { Id= 2, name = "B"},
      new LicenseDataGrid { Id= 3, name = "C"}
  };

foreach (var license in list)
{
   Console.WriteLine(license.Id);
}

list.RemoveAt(1);
for (var i = 0; i < list.Count; i++) // here's magic
{
   list[i].Id = i + 1;
}

foreach (var license in list)
{
    Console.WriteLine(license.Id);
}
```

You should update your `Id` field manually after removing element from the list. It is simple because [List](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.list-1?view=netframework-4.8) has the default [Item](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.list-1.item?view=netframework-4.8) property, so you will know the real position in the list for the every element.

Comment: Foreach and Index of , is a bit overkill. `List<T>` use a `T[]` reference https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/collections/generic/list.cs,174 . Using  a simple for loop you can access to elment using their index using `list[i]`, that way you only store an int and don't have to make call to index of (https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/collections/generic/equalitycomparer.cs,894804338236ebbe).